# Creating a game where the computer guesses a value through inputs of <,> or =

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a game where i think of a number in my head. And then the computer guesses the number through me telling it if its guess is too low or high.

This is what I've come up with but i am pretty lost tbh.

```
maxguess = 100
minguess = 1

count = 0

print("Think of a number between {} and {}".format(minguess,maxguess))

def midpoint(maxguess, minguess) :
    z = ((maxguess + minguess)/2)

def guessing(x) :
    print("Is you number greater (>) , equal (=) ,or less (<) than" ,z,)
    print("please answer <,=, or >! >")
    x = input()
    if x == (">") :
       minpoint = z 
       count += 1
       continue
    elif x == ("<") : 
       maxpoint = z
       count += 1
       continue
    elif x == ("=") :
       print ("I have guessed it!")
       count += 1
       break

print("I needed {} steps!".format(count))
```

Answer (score 3):

Purposely not a complete solution, but some hints for you:

I'd recommend avoiding the global variables like `count`, `maxguess`, and `minguess`. Instead, make a function that holds all these variables.

Change your `midpoint` function to return z instead, then call it inside your `guessing` function.

Your `continue` and `break` functions would need to be inside a `for` or `while` loop. Since you aren't sure how many iterations you need to guess the number, I think a `while` loop would make sense here

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Much appreciated. I'll work on this.

Answer (score 2):

Your functions are never run. On a style point, bring all your 'main' statements down to the bottom so they're together. After the prompt to think of a number, you need to call the guessing() function. When you call it, you should pass the minguess and maxguess values to it.

I can see what you're trying to do with the if...elif statements, but they need to be in a *while True:* block. So should the three statements preceding them so the script repeatedly asks for new advice from you.

Either bring the content of the midpoint() function into guessing() or make it return the value of z.

You also offer the user a choice of '>1' but don't handle it - and you don't need it as far as I can tell.

You never use minpoint or maxpoint - and you dont need them. Call the midpoint function instead and pass it the appropriate values, e.g., if '>', z = midpoint(z, maxguess).

Also, you're going to spend forever trying to get it to guess as you are using floats. Make sure everything is an integer.

Finally, you should add some code to manage input that isn't expected, i.e., not '<', '>' or '='.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
minguess=1
maxguess=100
z=50
count=0
print("Think of a number between 1 and 100")
condition = True
while condition:

    z=((maxguess + minguess)//2)
    print("Is your number greater (>) , equal (=) ,or less (<) than" ,z,)
    print("Please answer <,=, or >! >")
    x = input()
    if x == (">"):
        minguess=z
        count += 1
    elif x == ("<") : 
        maxguess=z
        count += 1
    elif x == ("=") :
        print ("I have guessed it!")
        count += 1
        condition=False
```

Comment: I gave you the whole code as I made sure it worked and it was annoying so yea, there the code. You can check this code when your done or something as that works for me.

Comment: Why is everyone making it complex, all you do is get rid of the def function and add a while loop. Simple

Comment: Thank you Tommy. This solution seems simple and effective.

Comment: No problem, it uses the while loop to keep it going until it is equal, where it makes the condition false and stops it, make sure to use // otherwise it will divide to the proper division, not to a whole number.